# Checking CRUD for Static SobjectType

Tags: security, sobjecttype, crud

I am enforcing CRUD permissions for mainly custom objects.

Doing it this way

```
Boolean isUpdateable = Schema.sObjectType.Custom_Object__c.isUpdateable();
```

works, and it seems to avoid a describe call.  But obviously it is preferable to pass a static object type to a Utils method to make the code as reusable as possible.  Something like:

```
    public static Boolean hasUpdatePermission(Schema.Sobjecttype sobj){
       return sobj.isUpdateable(); 
    }
```

Here it doesn't recognize the method.  What data type is Schema.sObjectType.Custom_Object__c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the concrete type is a `Schema.DescribeSObjectResult`

Writing it the other way `CustomObject__c.SObjectType.getDescribe()` lines it up with the docs:
[salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_Schema_SObjectType_getDescribe.htm](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_Schema_SObjectType_getDescribe.htm)

Comment: It works.  I assume that DescribeSObjectResult would need a getDescribe(), but it looks like it's implicit

Comment: Nice. I always used to mix up `SObjectType` and `DescribeSObjectResult` - the latter is returned by a `getDescribe` on the former.